# Is that possible to build/export as WebGL in Unity Daydream (Google VR)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr, virtual-reality, unity-webgl, daydream

I trying to make an VR app (iOS & Android). But I want to build web-version also.

Im using [Unity Google Daydream](https://unity3d.com/partners/google/daydream) version. And when I build Android and iOS app, its ok.

But when I trying to change platform to **WebGL** its say **No WebGL module loaded**. *(as I tried, in normal version we can selecte and install WebGL module, But Daydream version is not)*

[image: No WebGL]

**Questions :**

- This WebGL module is just for normal Unity version ? not in Daydream version ?
- Any trick to build WebGL version with Unity Google Daydream version ? *(I dont really need Google cardboard module (stereo) supported)*

Answer (score 1):

According to a reply from Unity, *you can't*.

You must etheir use the normal [Unity version](https://store.unity.com/front-page) or [Unity 5.6](https://unity3d.com/unity/beta) which is still in beta mode but it supports both WebGL and Daydream.